# Cannot save shipment

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, order-status

Unfortunately My Magento Backend Shows error While Ship order in

```
Cannot save shipment.
```

I don't know what is the problem recently only it happend

My `exception.log`

```
016-02-29T13:44:58+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '100000257' for key 'UNQ_SALES_FLAT_SHIPMENT_INCREMENT_ID'' in /home/domain/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 /home/domain/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /home/domain/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/domain/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /home/domain/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /home/domain/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `sa...', Array)
#5 /home/domain/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `sa...', Array)
#6 /home/domain/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(576): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `sa...', Array)
#7 /home/domain/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(453): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->insert('sales_flat_ship...', Array)
#8 /home/domain/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order/Abstract.php(425): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment))
#9 /home/domain/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(318): Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment))
#10 /home/domain/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Transaction.php(151): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#11 /home/domain/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/ShipmentController.php(120): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Transaction->save()
#12 /home/domain/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/ShipmentController.php(220): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_ShipmentController->_saveShipment(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment))
#13 /home/domain/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_ShipmentController->saveAction()
#14 /home/domain/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('save')
#15 /home/domain/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#16 /home/domain/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#17 /home/domain/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#18 /home/domain/public_html/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#19 {main}

Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '100000257' for key 'UNQ_SALES_FLAT_SHIPMENT_INCREMENT_ID', query was: INSERT INTO `sales_flat_shipment` (`store_id`, `total_qty`, `email_sent`, `order_id`, `customer_id`, `shipping_address_id`, `billing_address_id`, `increment_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, '2016-02-29 13:44:58', '2016-02-29 13:44:58')' in /home/domain/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:235
Stack trace:
#0 /home/domain/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/domain/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/domain/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/domain/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `sa...', Array)
#4 /home/domain/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `sa...', Array)
#5 /home/domain/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(576): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `sa...', Array)
#6 /home/domain/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(453): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->insert('sales_flat_ship...', Array)
#7 /home/domain/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order/Abstract.php(425): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment))
#8 /home/domain/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(318): Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment))
#9 /home/domain/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Transaction.php(151): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#10 /home/domain/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/ShipmentController.php(120): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Transaction->save()
#11 /home/domain/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/ShipmentController.php(220): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_ShipmentController->_saveShipment(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment))
#12 /home/domain/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_ShipmentController->saveAction()
#13 /home/domain/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('save')
#14 /home/domain/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#15 /home/domain/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#16 /home/domain/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#17 /home/domain/public_html/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#18 {main}
```

Comment: Check in the exception.log in var/log folder in your magento root. Sometimes for actions like these, Magento logs the exceptions in exception.log

Comment: yes i check that it shows some error for opening only shows error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this i followed this it's working fine

```
UPDATE eav_entity_store
INNER JOIN eav_entity_type ON eav_entity_type.entity_type_id = eav_entity_store.entity_type_id
SET eav_entity_store.increment_last_id='XXXXXXXXXX'
WHERE eav_entity_type.entity_type_code='shipment';
```

This Means
    xxxxxx **Your last Shipment order id **

Comment: work as a charm, you have my upvote

Answer (score 1):

To fix this issue. You need to change your `increment_last_id` of your `shipment` entity type.

By default in magento shipment entity type is **8**. Which you can find in `eav_entity_type` table.

You need to change this value for store. The `increment_last_id` is in `eav_entity_store` table. You can run following query to update your shipment `increment_last_id`. Where **X** is your new `increment_last_id` and **STORE_ID_HERE** is your store id to whom you changing shipment `increment_last_id`.

```
UPDATE eav_entity_store
       INNER JOIN eav_entity_type
         ON eav_entity_type.entity_type_id = eav_entity_store.entity_type_id
SET    eav_entity_store.increment_last_id = 'X'
WHERE  eav_entity_type.entity_type_code = 'shipment'
       AND eav_entity_store.store_id = {STORE_ID_HERE};
```

**OR**

```
UPDATE `eav_entity_store` SET `increment_last_id` = 'X' WHERE `entity_type_id` = '8';
```

**Notice that the value for increment_last_id already contains the increment_prefix. Use your entity_type increment_prefix**

For more details check here : https://www.warpconduit.net/2012/04/18/how-to-change-the-order-increment-id-and-prefix-in-magento/

Hope this helps.

Comment: What i need to add increment_last_id = 'X' and  eav_entity_store.store_id = {STORE_ID_HERE};

Comment: Please give some examble

Comment: I have mentioned in my answer that Where `X` is your new `increment_last_id`(Greater number of your last shipment id ) and `STORE_ID_HERE` is your store_id.

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO `db_name`.`eav_entity_store` (`entity_store_id`, `entity_type_id`, `store_id`, `increment_prefix`, `increment_last_id`) VALUES ('{last_id_of_eav_entity_store}', '{entity_type_id_from_eav_entity_type_for_SHIPMENT}', '{store_id}', '1', '{copy_from_admin_sales_shipment_last#}');